# How do I pass data from my function to the data method?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, promise

I'm trying to pass data from my API to the `data` method, in Vue.

```js
       data(){
          return{
            name:"" 
          }
       },
           
    
       methods: {    
        
              getData(){
                useData.data("profile",  this.route.params.id).then(function(r: any){          
                   r.data;         
                });
              }

        },
    
        created(){
        
          this.name=this.getData();
        
        }
```

And I display the it in my template like this:

`{{name}}`

The problem is that it doesn't work. It doesn't show any error but it doesn't display anything either.

If I change the function `getData()` to something like:

```js
      getData(){
         return "123";
      }
```

It successfully displays 123 in the template. I believe it has something to do with the promise.

If I try to assign value to `name` directly inside the function `getData()`, I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of
> undefined

So how could I get the data from the http request and send it to the `data` method?

Comment: Your `getData` method needs to `return` if you want to assign `name` like you do.

Comment: Thank you but I had tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: Because it is a Promise. You need to `await` for the return value.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by just changing

from

```
getData(){
   useData.data("profile",  this.route.params.id).then(function(r: any){          
         r.data;         
   });
}
```

to

```
 getData(){
    useData.data("profile",  this.route.params.id).then(r =>{          
        this.name=r.data;         
    });
 }
```

I guess that`this` doesn't work with regular functions

If someone knows if there's any way to use  `this` within a regular function, please, tell me how.

Comment: OK but this is more than simply fixing the original code.

Comment: I would like to know a way to fix the original code actually. Hahaha, if you have any ideas...because I actually just wanted to pass the data from my function getData to the Vue's data method...doesn't matter how. But it worked.